# Checking a URL redirection from terminal

Tags: command-line, curl, cache

I have a server with a lot of domain redirections that I want to check.

I do not trust the way browsers cache the domains so I am never sure if I am seeing it live or seeing a redirection from cache.

Is there a way to test the redirection from terminal and seeing the real thing without any kind of cache?

I have tried

```
curl -I http://example.com
```

as stated by other posts but it is not providing any important information on my Mac.

It gives me this:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 18:26:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Fix whatever's causing the 406, likely not sending an acceptable content type, method, and request body combination. Chrome dev tools has a copy request as curl feature: visit the page in browser, then copy as curl for a starting point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`curl` has the `-L` option

> -L, --location
>                 (HTTP)  If  the  server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code),
>                 this option will make curl redo the request on the new place
>   ...

Therefore you could use

`curl -L example.com`

which should give the document after all redirects.

Additionally, you can supply the verbose flag `-v` which will state that it is being redirected.

Comment: not working for me. It gives me this `<html><head><title>Error 406 - Not Acceptable</title><head><body><h1>Error 406 - Not Acceptable</h1><p>Generally a 406 error is caused because a request has been blocked by Mod Security. If you believe that your request has been blocked by mistake please contact the web site owner.</p></body></html>`

Comment: A `4xx` HTTP status code is a client error. If the server wants the client to redirect, it should use a `3xx` status code. Many clients don't expect to continue looking for a document when they're told there's an error with their request.

Comment: all redirects have code 301

Comment: Which yours does not. "3xx Redirection - This class of status code indicates the client must take additional action to complete the request. Many of these status codes are used in URL redirection." - [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)